# how to fill polygon with image in opengles 2.0 android

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping, texture2d

I am new to android opengl development.I want to fill polygon with image as shown below using opengl-es 2.0 in android. I am able to draw square,triangle but not able to fill it with repeating image. Anyone know please help me.

Square.java

```
public class Square {

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;" +
        "void main() {" +                       
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        " v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;" +
        "}";      
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;"+
        "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);" +
        "}"; 
private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float squareCoords[] = {

     -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   // top left
     1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // top right
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
     -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f   // bottom left
     };

final float[] previewTextureCoordinateData =
    {
        0.0f,0.0f, // top left
        1.0f,0.0f, // Top-right
        1.0f,1.0f, // Bottom-right          
        0.0f,1.0f,  // Bottom-left
    };
private int textureDataHandle;
private int textureUniformHandle;
private int textureCoordinateHandle;

private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; 
float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };
private int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId){    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
{
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

    // Read in the resource
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

    // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

    // Set filtering
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
    bitmap.recycle();
}

if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
}

return textureHandle[0];}

 public Square(Context c) {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            squareCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
           drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer texCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(previewTextureCoordinateData.length * 4);
    texCoordinates.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = texCoordinates.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(previewTextureCoordinateData);
    textureBuffer.position(0);


    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    textureDataHandle = loadTexture(c, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    textureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_TextureCoordinates");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 
            0, textureBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateHandle);

    textureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_TextureUnit");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureDataHandle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUniformHandle, 0);      

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}}
```

[image: Fill polygon with Image]

Comment: What have you tried? You seem to know about textures since you tagged the question with them. So look around for some texture tutorials. For the texture to repeat all you need is to set the coordinates that way and use repeat parameter on the texture.

Comment: @MaticOblak..I want to fill simple square with image. I want this kind of texture or pattern in polygon using opengl-es

Comment: Again: Have you searched for drawing a texture? If not then take a look into it. If yes then be more specific on where your issue is.

Comment: @MaticOblak I have search and able to render image but image will occupy whole square it will not repeating. I am adding my square class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the texture to repeat you need to set such texture coordinates. A texture coordinate is a relative pixel position in the texture where `(0.0, 0,0)` is the top-left position on the image and `(1.0, 1.0)` is the bottom right. Now no matter the vertex coordinates the texture part shown will always be the same. In your case then

```
final float[] previewTextureCoordinateData =
    {
        0.0f,0.0f, // top left
        1.0f,0.0f, // Top-right
        1.0f,1.0f, // Bottom-right          
        0.0f,1.0f,  // Bottom-left
    };
```

means you will be drawing a whole texture on the object. To make it repeat for instance 3 times in each of dimensions you need to multiply these:

```
final float[] previewTextureCoordinateData =
    {
        0.0f,0.0f, // top left
        1.0f*3.0,0.0f, // Top-right
        1.0f*3.0,1.0f*3.0, // Bottom-right          
        0.0f,1.0f*3.0,  // Bottom-left
    };
```

The repeating is already enabled on the texture so that should be it.